# I can't find the style for the border in the sidebar

Tags: css

I've been trying to figure out for hours where the border from the sidebar is coming from in this site: [http://sökoptimering.se/](http://s%C3%B6koptimering.se/)

Here's a screenshot of what I'm trying to look for: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UikYy.jpg

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's this

```
#entries-area {
    background: url(images/content-main-bg.png) repeat-y top right;
}
```

and

```
#entries-area-content {
    background: url(images/content-area-topbg.jpg) no-repeat top right;
}
```

Comment: yeah I found that too, problem is I cant find the upper part of it. if you try to  disable the background style it's only up to the 4th link in the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter properties by 'background' and just check elements with keybord arrows one-by-one. be careful some of them have duplicated rules - so when you disable one, the second is still showing the image

background you're looking for is set for this elements

```
#entries-area-content
#entries-area
```

[image]